# What this version means? NetFXspW7.050727-4900 and win7RTMGDR.050727-4900

Tags: .net

I have below error msg and I want to know more information about what this means?

`NetFXspW7.050727-4900` = version of .NET on Windows 7?

`win7RTMGDR.050727-4900` = what is this RTMGDR?

```
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4952 (**win7RTMGDR.050727-4900**)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (**NetFXspW7.050727-4900**)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RTM` is normally release to manufacturing, the copy that was sent to the people responsible for shipping the CD or ISO image or however it's distributed.

`GDR` is general distribution release, files delivered from Windows Update, as opposed to limited distribution release which are not pushed out to everyone.

You're expected to apply LDR fixes if you're affected (e.g., an LDR fix for IE9 will not affect those still running IE6). On the other hand, a security fix for a flaw in NTFS will affect everyone, and they're always GDR.

This is as much down to how Microsoft manages their source code control and build systems as it is to version "numbers".

Those labels are probably *exactly* that. Labels given to a whole bucketload of files that shipped as a certain "release". Similar to the way a simple source control system would just grab the latest of every source file, package it up into a 1.7.1 release, then apply a label of REL_1_7_1 to all those source files so that you can easily rebuild or patch a specific level.